# How to enable test connection button in Airflow in v2.7.1

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-taskflow

Test connection button is disabled in Airflow because I am using 2.7 + version. How to enable it?

I am not sure of steps. Please guide. Also I have installed Airflow with Kubernetes helm chart. Not sure where I need to make change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is clickable only for Providers (hooks) that support it. Meaning that the hook needs to implement the [`test_connection`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e8538493a9f74f61834b19e840c7b9987269d45d/airflow/models/connection.py#L452-L466) function which allows the functionality.

In cases where the button is not available you can test the connection works by simply using it. Invoke a simple DAG that uses the connection.